# Sunspot / solr complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Say i have some products that i want to search.

I want to find the products that are within some min and/or max values say length, width and height.

I can do :

```
any_of do

  with(:length).greater_than_or_equal_to(length_min)
  with(:length).less_than_or_equal_to(length_max)

  with(:width).greater_than_or_equal_to(width_min)
  with(:width).less_than_or_equal_to(width_min)

  with(:height).greater_than_or_equal_to(height_min)
  with(:height).less_than_or_equal_to(height_min)
end
```

This will give me products that match any of these.

I want to return all products but sorted by the products that match the most criteria.

So for example :

Product A that is within all the length, width and height ranges with be first, then Product C that matches just length and width and then Product B that doesnt match any of the length, width or height ranges.

Anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks a lot
Rick

Comment: I was going to say that you should sort by `:score`, but when I tried, these `with` don't seem to affect the relevance score...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation on https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot, it appears that by using the `any_of do` will return results if any of the items match any criteria.

```
# Posts that do not have an expired time or have not yet expired
Post.search do
  any_of do
    with(:expired_at).greater_than(Time.now)
    with(:expired_at, nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: kobaltz yes but i need to return the results in order of how MANY of the criteria that each procut matched and also the results that didnt match but these will be at the bottom of the search results order.  any ideas ?  thanks